How can fetched data be passed around different pages in Next.js 14?
I'm new to Next.js, and trying to wrap my head around working without state-management (e.g. Redux), but can't seem to figure this one out:
I have a Strapi backend setup that's accepting user registrations and logins. Everything in my Next app is working as expected, I'm protecting a couple of routes using the middleware.ts:
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import type { NextRequest } from "next/server";
import { getUserMeLoader } from "./lib/data/services/get-user-me-loader";

export async function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  const user = await getUserMeLoader();
  const currentPath = request.nextUrl.pathname;

  if (currentPath.startsWith("/dashboard") && user.ok === false) {
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/login", request.url));
  }

  return NextResponse.next();
}

My question is in regards to accessing the user data inside of the dashboard and its subpages without calling the backend once more. In addition to just being logged-in or signed-out, the user has a role which I am using to determine what should be displayed inside certain pages of the dashboard. Or, as another example, logged-in users can submit some application form that is sending its submissions to some third-party provider, and when that page is opened I need to check if that user already has a submitted application.
Taking that last example, I then need to call the same getUserMeLoader that I used in the middleware.
export default async function ApplyPage() {
  const { user } = await getUserMeLoader();

  const applied = await fetchAlreadyApplied({
    email: user.email.toLowerCase(),
  });

  if (applied) {
    return <div>You already applied</div>
  }

  return <>...form</>
}

I also noticed that if I place a console.log inside of getUserMeLoader it's logging a bunch of times since I am using it in multiple dashboard pages so I assume whenever it's building that endpoint is called from each of the pages.
Would love any kind of input on how to handle cases such as these.

try context api, so on layout.tsx you can call the getrole() and then access the role value in all child  / other component.
